# intent putextra map android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

Activity <- first   , I want to intent.putExtra (data) ... 
  but it's only put only one marker ...
  it's not put (data) many marker ???
  Help me, pllz ??

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))
                        .position(new LatLng(dataLat,dataLong)).title(dataTitle)
                        .snippet(dataAddress)); 
                 allMarkersMap.put(marker, DetailActivity.class);

                 map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Class cls = allMarkersMap.get(marker);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,cls);

                 intent.putExtra("Title",dataTitle);


                // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), phone + "-"+  dataTitle +"-"+ dataAddress + "-" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 startActivity(intent);
```

Activity <- second

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
tvtitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);


        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        String dataTitle = bundle.getString("Title");
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTitle)).setText("Title:   " + dataTitle);



        //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: help me plz :(   I think "Final " don't read ??

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you explain better what the problem is? What isn't working as you expect?

Comment: ex : Title : abc , abd , ....
When I intent from activy 1 -> acvity 2 
it's intent abc -> abc and abd - > abc 

problem is abd -> abc ? <- wrong < when intent acvity ?? 
it's abd -> abd (right)

Comment: I'm sorry, I still cannot understand your problem :-(

Comment: Intent 2 activity  ????

Comment: the extras in an `Intent` are in a `Bundle`. This is just a hash map with name/value pairs. If you want to add multiple items then you will need to add arrays as extras.